# When to load .env variables in NodeJS app?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, environment-variables, lifecycle

I am coding a simple NodeJS Express REST API, using TypeScript. I have some environment variables that I load with [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

I access my `.env` variables at two different stages in my code: `index.ts`, which is my start file, and in a `MyControllerClass.ts` file. To access these variables, the code is `process.env.MY_ENV_VAR`. To load them for the application, the code is `dotenv.config()`.

As my `index.ts` file seems to be the root of my program (I configure my app in it), I use `dotenv.config()` to load my `.env` file for the rest of the program. However, in my `MyControllerClass.ts` file, in the constructor, if I do `console.log(process.env.MY_ENV_VAR)`, I get "`undefined`". I could workaround this by adding a `dotenv.config()` in my constructor (it works) but it's nonsense to me to have it here.

How do I use `dotenv.config()` once and for all in my program, in a readable manner (like in an appropriate .ts file)? and more generally: what is a NodeJS Express loading cycle?

Here is a sample of the file structure of my code

```
src
├── index.ts
├── Authentication
│   └── authentication.router.ts
│   └── authentication.controller.ts
```

Here is the code of index.js

```
/**
 * Required External Modules
 */
 import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
 import express from "express";
 import cors from "cors";
 import helmet from "helmet";
 import { authenticationRouter } from "./authentication/authentication.router"

 dotenv.config();

 /**
 * App Variables
 */
 if(!process.env.PORT) {
    process.exit(1);
}
const PORT: number = parseInt(process.env.PORT as string, 10);
const app = express();

/**
 *  App Configuration
 */
 app.use(helmet());
 app.use(cors());
 app.use(express.json());
 app.use(authenticationRouter);

 app.use("api/authenticate/", authenticationRouter);
/**
 * Server Activation
 */
 app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
  });
```

Here is the code of authentication.router.ts

```
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
import { AuthenticatorController } from "./authentication.controller";
export const authenticationRouter = express.Router();
const authenticatorController = AuthenticatorController.getInstance();

authenticationRouter.post("/api/authenticate", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {   
    try {
        if (await authenticatorController.authenticate(req.body.login, req.body.password)) {
            res.send({"status": "ok"})
        } else
            res.send({"status": "Error"})
    } catch (e) {
        console.debug(e)
        res.send({"status": "500"});
    }
    
});
```

Here is the code of authentication.controller.ts

```
import { ClientSecretCredential } from "@azure/identity";
import { SecretClient } from "@azure/keyvault-secrets";
import { Authenticator } from "./api/Authenticator";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

export class AuthenticatorController implements Authenticator {
    
    private static singleInstance: AuthenticatorController | null = null;
    private azureSecretCredential= new ClientSecretCredential(
        process.env.AZURE_TENANT_ID as string,
        process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_ID as string,
        process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET as string);
    private azureSecretClient = new SecretClient(
        process.env.KEY_VAULT_URL as string,
        this.azureSecretCredential);

    private constructor () {}

    public static getInstance(): AuthenticatorController {
        if (this.singleInstance === null) {
            this.singleInstance = new AuthenticatorController();
        }
        return this.singleInstance;
    }

    public async authenticate(login: string, password: string): Promise<Boolean> {
        let isAuthenticated = false;

        try {
            const secret = await this.azureSecretClient.getSecret(login)
            if (secret.name === login) {
                if (secret.value === password) {
                    isAuthenticated = true;
                }
            }
        }   catch (e) {
            console.debug(e);
        }
            return isAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the 'MyClass.ts' file is a router, that I need to configure my app, in index.ts. So that means that to mount my index.ts file, NodeJS needs the MyClass.ts file to be mounted itself, right? So that would be normal that MyClass.ts is the start in this scenario... But if I have several classes and dependencies, I still want to load my env variables once and in a file that makes sense, like index.ts, not in a RandomUserModel.ts file or anything...

Answer (score 3):

You only call [`dotenv.config()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) once:

> As early as possible in your application, require and configure
> dotenv.
>
> `require('dotenv').config()`

Therefore index.ts seems to be correct, `process.env` should then hold your parsed values. Maybe you can use something like this to make sure, data is parsed correctly:

```
const result = dotenv.config();

if (result.error) {
  throw result.error;
}

console.log(result.parsed);
```

**Edit:**

You can try the following. I changed your exports a bit, because there is no need for a singleton within your controller.

*authentication.router.ts:*

```
// Imports (no dotenv; no dotenv.config())
// [...]

// Import controller
import { authenticatorController } from "./authentication.controller";

export const authenticationRouter = express.Router();

// Adding routes
// [...]
```

*authentication.controller.ts:*

```
// Imports (no dotenv; no dotenv.config())
// [...]

class AuthenticatorController implements Authenticator {
  // [...]
}

export const authenticatorController = new AuthenticatorController();
```

*index.ts:*

```
// Imports (dotenv)
// [...]

const { error, parsed } = dotenv.config();

if (error) {
  throw error;
}

console.log(parsed);

// [...]

 app.use("api/authenticate/", authenticationRouter);

// [...]
```

Comment: I know, I have read this part of the documentation of dotenv. But as I am trying to say, I do not know where is the 'earliest' of my program...

Comment: Do you call something like `node index.js` to start your application? Then it should be this file.

Comment: After my Typescript compiler has done its work, I obtain an index.js file, indeed. I had not thought about adding dotenv.config() in it. I guess you are right, it could work, but if I had some other option, I would like to add it in my .ts files, and not in my js files, that I consider being my distribution. Am I making any sense? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of your app?

Comment: Yes, I have just edited my question so you can have the full context of my situation. Thank you.

Comment: Please see my update. Hopefully a helpful one :)

Comment: I have seen and tested it. It does not work sadly :'| , but I sincerely appreciate the investment. Any idea left?

Comment: Does `console.log(parsed);` log the correct values? How do you compile and run your project?

Comment: It does contain all my variables. My command is tsc --build && node /dist/index.js